# Unable to hide Google Maps marker on Android

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

I have an issue with the Maps API on Android.
When I create a marker and add it to the map it is correctly displayed. See code below:

```
// Create a list for referencing markers
val markers: MutableList<Marker> = mutableListOf()

// Add marker to map
val markerOptions = MarkerOptions().position(position).icon(anIcon).title("A title")
val marker = map.addMarker(markerOptions)

// Save marker in list
markers.add(marker)
```

Later on, when I tried to hide each marker by iterating through the list of markers and setting the isVisible attribute to false (see code below) it does not work. All the markers are still displayed.

```
for(marker in markers)
    marker.isVisible = false
```

What can explain this behavior?

Extra information: If I call `marker.remove()`, the markers are properly removed from the map
Extra information: If I set the visibility to false when I add the marker to the map in the first place the marker is not displayed.

Comment: `isVisible` worked only with minSdkVersion 21

Comment: minSdkVersion is 24 in my case

Answer (score 0):

The reason appears to be that `isVisible` is a *getter* method that checks whether a marker is visible or not. To make the marker invisible you should use `marker.setVisible(false)`. You can learn more on this in Google's Marker class [Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/maps/model/Marker#developer-guide).

Hope this helps!